# Exiting out of the iteratable Observable upon successful response

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2

I have a scenario in which I've to bridge the nonreactive code with Reactive Code.

Consider the following scenario.

I have a list of 3 URLs in an `ArrayList`. I want to call each URL in the order they are inside the `ArrayList`. I can call only 1 URL at a time. If the first URL returns a successful Response, I want to call `onComplete()` and don't wanna execute the remaining URL. However, if the response is an error, I want to execute the next URL in the list. *I don't want RxJava to call `flatMap` for the next URL unless I get an error response for the previous URL.* Due to my primitive understanding of RxJava, I couldn't figure out a way to achieve this.

What I planned to do something like this:

```
Observable.fromIteratable(urlList)
.subscribeOn(Schedulars.io())
.flatMap(new Func(String url, String data) {
    SomeNetworkLibrary.getData(url)
    .OnResponse(new NewResponse() {
         public void onSuccess(String dataFromInternet) {return dataFromInternet;}
         public void onError(String errorMessage) {return errorMessage;)
    })
    // wait until we have response from the network call above and then return
    // I don't know what will be the cleanest and efficient way of waiting here.
});
```

**TLDR;**

I don't want `flatMap()` to be called before the results from the previous `flatMap()` have been returned.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the network api call into an `Observable` and then use `take(1)` after the flattening:

```
Observable.fromIteratable(urlList)
.subscribeOn(Schedulars.io())
.concatMapDelayError((String url, String data) -> {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        SomeNetworkLibrary.getData(url)
        .OnResponse(new NewResponse() {
            public void onSuccess(String dataFromInternet) {
                emitter.onNext(dataFromInternet);
                // don't call emitter.onComplete() so that
                // concatMapDelayError doesn't switch to the next source
            }
            public void onError(String errorMessage) {
                emitter.onError(errorMessage);
            }
        );
    });
    // wait until we have response from the network call above and then return
    // I don't know what will be the cleanest and efficient way of waiting here.
})
.take(1);
```